# Cannot compare returned enum to enum

Tags: c++, enums

I'm having a problem where I have an enum called `tile`, a function called `tileread` that returns a `tile` value and an `if` statement that compares the returned value to a static one, also of `tile`:

```
enum tile{ tile_void, tile_flat };

tile tileread( const int x, const int y ) {
    if( x < 0 || x >= level_length || y < 0 || y >= level_width ) {
        return tile_void;
    }
    return level_tile[x][y];
}

if( tileread[ aux_int_1 ][ aux_int_2 ] == tile_void ) {
    player_vel[2] -= player_grav;
}
```

However, the compiler throws an error saying there is "no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'tile(int, int)' and 'tile')"

I've searched for a while now and nothing points to this problem. How do I solve this?

Comment: Typo?  Shouldn't `if( tileread[ aux_int_1 ][ aux_int_2 ] == tile_void )` be `if( tileread(aux_int_1, aux_int_2) == tile_void )`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `tileread` as a function.  And

```
tileread[ aux_int_1 ][ aux_int_2 ]
```

is (normally) the syntax for accessing an element in an array of arrays (or array of pointers, or pointer to pointer), not for calling a function.  You need instead:

```
if ( tileread( aux_int_1, aux_int_2 ) == tile_void ) {
```

and then it should work.

Now, if you really want to use the square brackets as though `tileread` were an array of arrays, you could set that up using operator overloading.  The first step in operator overloading is to think about whether you really should be using operator overloading.  How much does the special syntax make sense for the problem you're trying to solve?  Will it be more useful to a programmer using your interface, or more confusing to a programmer coming across it?  (And even if you never intend to share your code, that programmer can be you after you put the project aside and then come back to it months or years later.)

If you decide it will be worth it, defining the name `tileread` to allow `tileread[ aux_int_1 ][ aux_int_2 ]` could look something like this:

```
class TileReadType {
public:
    constexpr TileReadType() noexcept = default;
private:
    class RowProxy {
    public:
        tile operator[] ( int y ) const;
    private:
        constexpr explicit RowProxy( int x ) noexcept : x(x) {}
        int x;
        friend TileReadType;
    };
public:
    constexpr RowProxy operator[] ( int x ) const noexcept
    { return RowProxy(x); }
};
constexpr TileReadType tileread{};

// Either mark "inline", or put in a source file:
tile TileReadType::RowProxy::operator[] ( int y ) const
{
    // Code that was in the function goes here:
    if( x < 0 || x >= level_length || y < 0 || y >= level_width ) {
        return tile_void;
    }
    return level_tile[x][y];
}
```

Comment: I used to access level_tile directly and got confused after the switch. Also, I have no idea about what your code does other than solve my problem in a crazy-awesome way.

Comment: Probably too crazy, really.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am, like always, terrible at looking for stuff. `tileread[ aux_int_1, aux_int 2 ]` should be `tileread( aux_int_1, aux_int 2 )`.

If it was a snake it would have bitten me several times. Thanks, @NathanOliver!

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings to a high setting.  The compiler should have been able to identify the problem for you.